# Ionic: Does not show CameraPreview

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cross-platform

I have set up a camera application that does not want to show the `CameraPreview`. The code checks for authorization of camera and returns true for that.

When I start the application it asks for the permission and then there simply happens nothing.

**Question**: What else could I check?

While running the app I have opened a terminal with `adb shell`. The only line that *could* give a hint (but I do not get why):

```
09-08 11:30:34.336  4590  8923 W ExynosCamera1Parameters: [CAM_ID(0)][ParametersBack]-ERROR(getPreviewBayerCropSize[5777]): current BNS size(4032x3024) is NOT same with Hw BNS size(4032x2268)
```

the plugins I have installed - `cordova plugin list`:

```
cordova-plugin-camera 2.4.1 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-camera-preview 0.9.0 "cordova-plugin-camera-preview"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.1.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.5 "Console"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.4 "Device"
cordova-plugin-file 4.3.3 "File"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.0.3 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.2.2 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.1 "Whitelist"
cordova.plugins.diagnostic 3.6.7 "Diagnostic"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
```

The app contains only one page called "home".

home.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Diagnostic } from '@ionic-native/diagnostic';
import { CameraPreview, CameraPreviewPictureOptions, CameraPreviewOptions, CameraPreviewDimensions } from '@ionic-native/camera-preview';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public toastCtrl: ToastController,
    public diagnostic: Diagnostic,
    public cameraPreview: CameraPreview
    ) {
      this.checkPermissions();
  }

  async checkPermissions(): Promise<void> {
    const cameraPreviewOpts: CameraPreviewOptions = {
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      width: window.screen.width,
      height: window.screen.height,
      camera: 'rear',
      tapPhoto: true,
      previewDrag: true,
      toBack: true,
      alpha: 1
    };

    // picture options
    const pictureOpts: CameraPreviewPictureOptions = {
      width: 1280,
      height: 1280,
      quality: 85
    }

    const authorized = await this.diagnostic.isCameraAuthorized();

    if(authorized) {
      // start camera
      try {
        const result = await this.cameraPreview.startCamera(cameraPreviewOpts);
      // the program runs into here
        console.log("Camera Preview authorized: " + result);
      }
      catch (err) {
        console.log("Camera Preview authorized: " + err)
      }
    }
    else {pictureOpts
      const status = await this.diagnostic.requestCameraAuthorization();

      if(status == this.diagnostic.permissionStatus.GRANTED)
      {
        // start camera
        try {
          const result = await this.cameraPreview.startCamera(cameraPreviewOpts);
          console.log(result);
        }
        catch (err) {
          console.log(err)
        }
      }
      else {
          // Permissions not granted
          // Therefore, create and present toast
          this.toastCtrl.create({
            message: "Cannot access camera",
            position: "bottom",
            duration: 5000
          }).present();
      }
    }

  }

}
```

and the home.html:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Ionic Blank
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <ion-fab right top>
      <button ion-fab color="secondary" >
          <ion-icon name="md-color-wand"></ion-icon>
      </button>
  </ion-fab>

  <ion-fab right bottom>
      <button ion-fab color="primary" >
          <ion-icon name="md-camera"></ion-icon>
      </button>
  </ion-fab>
</ion-content>
```

I have imported everything to my `app.module.ts` :

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { Diagnostic } from '@ionic-native/diagnostic';
import { CameraPreview } from '@ionic-native/camera-preview';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    Diagnostic,
    CameraPreview,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: check in your App settings is camera permission is true or not  for your App

Comment: @sunielkalwani I have checked the settings on the device and they are activated

Comment: can you use chrome://inspect/#devices for debug attached your device with pc and open above link in browser it will show your device on browser as you move in your App it reflect in browser